# CREATE UNIQUE with labels and properties

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm using Neo4j 2.0.0-M06. Just learning Cypher and reading the docs. In my mind this query would work, but I should be so lucky...

I'm importing tweets to a mysql-database, and from there importing them to neo4j. If a tweet is already existing in the Neo4j database, it should be updated.

My query:

```
MATCH (y:Tweet:Socialmedia) WHERE
HAS (y.tweet_id) AND y.tweet_id = '123'
CREATE UNIQUE (n:Tweet:Socialmedia {
 body : 'This is a tweet', tweet_id : '123', tweet_userid : '321', tweet_username : 'example'
} )
```

Neo4j says: `This pattern is not supported for CREATE UNIQUE`

The database is currently empty on nodes with the matching labels, so there are no tweets what so ever in the Neo4j database.

What is the correct query?

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that Neo4j doesn't allow CREATE UNIQUE on single nodes, only when creating relationships?

Comment: soon, MERGE will replace CREATE UNIQUE for all cases. :) CREATE UNIQUE is currently the only way to make unique relationships, but definitely use MERGE for nodes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to use MERGE for this query, along with a unique constraint.

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT on (t:Tweet) ASSERT t.tweet_id IS UNIQUE;

MERGE (t:Tweet {tweet_id:'123'})
ON CREATE
SET t:SocialMedia, 
    t.body = 'This is a tweet', 
    t.tweet_userid = '321', 
    t.tweet_username = 'example';
```

This will use an index to lookup the tweet by id, and do nothing if the tweet exists, otherwise it will set those properties.

Comment: Great answer!  Helped me, too.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to point that one *can* use a combination of

1. CREATE CONSTRAINT and then a normal
2. CREATE   (without UNIQUE)

This is for cases where one expects a unique node and wants to throw an exception if the node unexpectedly exists. (Far cheaper than looking for the node before creating it).

*Also note that MERGE seems to take more CPU cycles than a CREATE. (It also takes more CPU cycles even if an exception is thrown)*

An alternative scenario covering CREATE CONSTRAINT, CREATE and MERGE (though admittedly not the primary purpose of this post).