# Neo4j: create unique not supported in JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc, neo4j

I have to create unique nodes in Neo4j, but this query is not correct because Neo4j says

> This pattern is not supported for CREATE UNIQUE

```
List<String> users = pUsers.collect();
    for(String u : users){
        if(u.equals("error"))
            continue;
        else{
            String cql = " CREATE UNIQUE (n:User {value:'" + u +"'})";
            st.executeUpdate(cql);
        }
```

How do I solve it?

Comment: Not sure if duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20003092/create-unique-with-labels-and-properties

Comment: I don't have to set new values and I'm using JDBC. Already checked that question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before using [CREATE UNIQUE](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/create-unique/) you need `MATCH` a node. After, use the matched node to create a unique pattern in the graph. `CREATE UNIQUE` will make the least change in the graph. I believe that what you need is a `MERGE`. The CREATE UNIQUE docs says:

> [MERGE](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/merge/) might be what you want to use instead of `CREATE UNIQUE`. Note
>   however, that `MERGE` doesn’t give as strong guarantees for
>   relationships being unique.

So you can adapt your code to:

```
List<String> users = pUsers.collect();
for(String u : users){
    if(u.equals("error"))
        continue;
    else{
        String cql = "MERGE (n:User {value:'" + u +"'})";
        st.executeUpdate(cql);
    }
}
```

Take a look in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33688537/6835358).